# getpass.getpass() hangs on ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, password-protection, getpass

I am using very simple code on ipython notebook for user to input password. Command hangs after user inputs the password. Here is my code sample -

```
import getpass

try:
    p = getpass.getpass()
except Exception as error:
    print('ERROR', error)
else:
    print('Password entered:', p)
```

I tried raw_input() as well, it hangs exactly the same way.

```
try:
    p = raw_input()
except Exception as error:
    print('ERROR', error)
else:
    print('Password entered:', p)
```

Any idea what's the solution for this.

I am running jupyter notebook on AWS server. Here are the version details -

```
    Python 2.7.13 |
    Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
    GCC 4.4.7 20120313 
    Red Hat 4.4.7-1
    IPython.__version__ '4.0.3'
```

Comment: What's your Jupyter notebook version? You IPython version is pretty old, considering that the most recent Python 2 version of IPython is 5.4. This could be causing the problem

Comment: Hi Louise, thanks for your response. This is what I found out about Jupyter version -jupyter                   1.0.0                    py27_1  
jupyter_client            4.1.1                    py27_0  
jupyter_console           4.1.0                    py27_0  
jupyter_core              4.0.6                    py27_0

Comment: Thank you Louise! Upgrading ipython solved the problem.

Comment: Louise, consider making an answer out of your comments as this was the right solutions.